# PutObject Access Denied when uploading csv file to S3

Tags: csv, amazon-s3, boto3

I am trying to use boto3 to upload csv file to s3, but I got "access denied" error.
below is part of my code. My IAM role is only grant "PutObject" permission for "my_bucket/google" folder but not the bucket's root.

```
###
df_pandas = df_spark.toPandas()
bucket = "my_bucket"
path = "google/report.csv"
csv_buffer = StringIO()
df_pandas.to_csv(csv_buffer)
s3_client = boto3.client("s3")
s3_client.put_object(Body=csv_buffer.getvalue(), Bucket=bucket, Key=path)
```

part of role s3 access policy:

```
Action:
       - "s3:PutObject"
       - "s3:DeleteObject"
Resource:
       - "arn:aws:s3:::my_bucket/google/*"
```

Comment: What is the IAM role?

Comment: role access to s3 bucket

Comment: Are you confident that your boto3 is actually using the role?

Comment: not sure how to confirm..

Comment: Use: `sts = boto3.client('sts')` and then `print(sts.get_caller_identity())`.